# How to create route for particular user using postgreSQL and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am working on a nodejs project where I am using postgreSQL. The project is related to creating a timesheet for employers. I have already created routes for showing timesheet and project.

```
app.route(/api/timesheet)
```

Now, I want to create a user model for this project and want to add particular timesheet for particular user. That means, user with particular userid can only view timesheet information related to this user. 
I can do it with mongodb but I would like to do it with postgreSQL. 
Thank you in any advance for your help.

Comment: Why not just create new route with id for example app.route('/api/user/:userId/timesheet') and then get that userId in controller from req.params and do what you wanted to do?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would like to create a route like this... I want to create only two user hard coded in the project as I don't have user model in the project. I don't know how to do it with postgreSQL. I just want to add two users in order to check how routes varies from user to user. If that is not possible, showing how to add new user schema would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

well, I've created users array where I have two users

```
const users = [
  {
      "id": "userId1",
      "email": "user1@mail.com",
      "password": "password"
  },
  {
      "id": "userId2",
      "email": "user2@mail.com",
      "password": "password2"
  }
```

];

then I created route as you wrote above

```
app.route('/api/timesheet')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;

    let user = users.find(user => user.id = id);
    res.json(user);
  });
```

Routes does not varies, route is always same, just it brings different data according to what you pass as a parameter.
if your GET request in query has "?userId=userId1" that will give you first object in response, so does if you pass second "userIs2", it will give you second one.

---

When I am using postgreSQL in nodejs project, I always do with  [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize)

---

You can define user schema like that

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
      return sequelize.define('user', {
        email: Sequelize.STRING,
        password: Sequelize.STRING
      });
  }
```

and then you will call `User.findById(id)` and it will give you user specified with id of course

sequelize is a powerful library so you should look at the documentation before use it

Comment: Thank you so much donquixote. One more concern I have regarding this. In app.route, instead of seeing user1 or user2, i would like to see in what projects they are included. Like the route u have written before.   app/userid/projects..how is this possible?

Comment: Also, I am getting "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" when I am trying to do "find" query in the user table.

Comment: You should store that projects in database, for example in your postgres. For the second question, this is good tutorial how to configure postgres with sequelize https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize. Do all these steps and you will get familiar how to do things you want to do

Comment: Projects are already in database. I wanted to know about the codes i need to write to fetch particular project that is created by particular user.